# Possible values of energies and impulses of virtual photon emitted by real electron

Tags: special-relativity, virtual-particles

I need to find the possible values of energies and impulses of virtual photon emitted by real electron. I don't understand how to compute it (look to the text below).

Let's introduce the free electron. Then let's use the frame in which it is at rest.

So the laws of energy-momentum conservation take the form
$$
E_{0} = E_{1} + E_{photon}, \quad 0 = p_{1} + p_{photon} .
$$
According to this, electron after photon emission must be virtual. 
What to do after that? Formally I have only two equations for four unknown values. What to do next? To use energy-impulse relation $p_{\mu}p^{\mu} = m^2c^2$ for virtual particles?

Comment: if you mean the photon and electron at the time corresponding to the the middle of [this graph](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Electron_self_energy.svg), there is not a single possible energy for them but there is a range of energies (following a probability distribution).

Comment: @AndreHolzner : so how to determine this range without QM?

Comment: It is a purely quantum mechanical effect.

Comment: @dmckee : but the range may be determined only by conservation laws without relativistic energy and momentum connection for the real particles, doesn't it?

Comment: No, when calculating the diagram you must integrate over all possible values of momentum for the internal lines (conserving momentum at all vertexes).